# After Win 10 Update (KB5028166) all browser javascript debuggers can't load form for debugging. How do I fix this issue?

Tags: windows-10, windows-update, javascript

Folks,
The most recent Win 10 Update (KB5028166) was automatically loaded on two 2 of my VMWare Virtual machines. Before the update I could use browser tools, Chrome & Edge & Firefox, to debug javascript code implemented on forms.
After the update the forms, and therefore the javascript, does not load correctly and I can't step through the code.

The Chrome Console displays the following error:

```
include.aspx?classes=ArasModules,ScriptSet1,TearOffMenuControllerNoCUI,pageReturnBlocker:31645     
GET http://192.168.32.131/InnovatorServer_Rheem_Dev/client/X-salt=9_14.0.8.35675-X/scripts/virtualGetForm?formId=A4E0A49FBFB946E3973B91F4EF9E6A50&formLastModifiedDate=2023-10-06T18:41:34.52&languageCode=en&itemTypeId=012B1A340CAC40A5B7730191BC5F8BDE&itemTypeLastModifiedDate=2023-09-24T11:18:48.43&databasehash=557536d80de1061032220f372c1019aa&mode=add 404 (Not Found)
```

This happens in all 3 browsers and started only after the 22H2 (KB5028166) was installed.
I have:

1. Uninstalled the 22H2 cumulative update
2. Tried to Uninstalled the 22H2 Security update but get the error:
   "An error occured, Not all updates were successfully uninstalled."
3. Ran SFC /scannow
4. Ran DISM:
   DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /CheckHealth;
   DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /ScanHealth;
   DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth;
5. Again tried to Uninstalled the 22H2 Security update but get the error:
   "An error occurred, Not all updates were successfully uninstalled."

I need to get the debugging environment running again so I can bill my client.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that KB5028166 is the last cumulative update you have installed?  It's over 3 months old. My point it's impossible for it to the most recent update and would have been installed over 2 months ago in July

Comment: Yes. These VM's are only used when needed. You can also see this in the Update history. I watched this update load on each VM.

Comment: Where are these HTTP resources served from? The same VM you're trying to load them on?

Comment: The error on the GET command is "404 (Not Found)". You should check why this page is missing: `http://192.168.32.131/InnovatorServer_Rheem_Dev/client`. Do other `http://` links succeed now?

Comment: >>Where are these HTTP resources served from? The same VM you're trying to load them on? << ++Good question! ++ First of all, I normally use the VM as a PLM server. So from the host machine [Dell 7770, I9, 64gb Ram, 6 TB storage] I use Edge to do the configuration and coding and then Chrome to do the debugging. This is where I first experienced the issue after the Win update. Next I repeated the issue using Chrome in the VM ... same result.

Comment: So it seems that the issue revolves around Security, where the path to the resource/source is being blocked from IIS retrieving it/finding it. Again I have used this methodology (PTC Windchill and Aras Innovator) for years (10+) and this is the first time I have had an issue like this.

Comment: >>Do other http:// links succeed now?<< I would say yes. I can use the VM as a server and interact with Aras Innovator with no problems. I can View, Create, Update, items using the VM as a server or from inside the VM. I only have issues when the browser debugger is loading the form javascript; in the server mode and from inside the VM.